# Why is the square root in the forward process of the Diffusion Model?

Tags: normal-distribution, python, mean, diffusion

I am trying to make sense of the diffusion model (one of the videos I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoKDTa5jHvg&t=706s). I came across this formula in the model:
[image]

This picture clearly explains the components of the formula. My question is the middle term - the mean. Why is the square root? At the very beginning, I thought it had something to do with the normal distribution. In Binominal Distribution,

mean =  =

variance = 2 =

SD =  = square root()

Where p is the probability of success and q = 1 - p.

It looks like this is not relevant. Then I think would it be related to the Root Mean Square? If yes, then why the X needs to be squared to start with?

Would anyone please help?

I have read this paper, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03585.pdf. Perhaps I overlooked, I can't find the answer from it.

Comment: The Normal distribution is highly relevant, because a diffusion is a limit of a random walk and the Normal distribution arises in such limits by virtue of the Central Limit Theorem.  Good keywords for searches are "Brownian Motion" and "Random Walk."

Answer (score -1):

The square root term in the diffusion function helps to ensure that the mean of the latent representation is the same as the mean of the real data distribution, even though the diffusion process adds noise to the latent representation.

This is important because it allows the diffusion model to learn the data distribution more effectively.

If we did not use the square root term, the mean of the latent representation would gradually shift away from the mean of the real data distribution as the diffusion process progressed. This would make it more difficult for the diffusion model to learn the data distribution.